# Angular/RxJS - Nested Observable - Refactor Statement

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm attempting to load departments from the server and populate a dropdown. If there's a *routeParam* (dep) present, I'd like to set the *formControl* (department) to the targeted item.

The nested *pipe* statements seems a bit off to me, but I'm still relatively new to RxJS. Is there a better way to write the assignment statement for *department$*?

```
public form: FormGroup;
public departments$: Observable<Department[]>;

constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private departmentService: DepartmentService) {}

get department() {
   return this.form.get('department') as FormControl;
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      department: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    });

    this.departments$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      switchMap(
        (params: ParamMap) => {
          return this.departmentService.getDepartments().pipe(
            tap(departments => {
              if (params.has('dep') && departments && departments.length) {
                this.department.setValue(departments.find(dep => dep.id === +params.get('dep')));
              }
            })
          );
        }
      )
    );
}
```

Comment: The logic looks ok for me, just need to reset control if it doesnt meet the `if` statement

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do the trick:

```js
this.departments$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(this.departmentService.getDepartments()),
  filter(([params, departments]) => {
    return params.has('dep') && departments.length
  }),
  tap(([params, departments]) => {
    this.department.setValue(
      departments.find(dep => dep.id === +params.get('dep'))
    );
  })
)
```

Might try `combineLatest` instead of `withLatestFrom` as well.

Comment: Never thought about using #rxjs withLatestFrom operator with function call that returns Observable :-O
Cool!

Answer (score 0):

```
this.departments$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
  map(params => params.get('dep')),
  switchMap(dep => this.departmentService.getDepartment(dep))
  // The find department logic belongs in the service
);
```